# Py_Initialize crash on windows OS

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x

I am using Qt 5.2 application and embedded Python C API into application.
I am using Python 3.3.4 and Windows 7 OS.

When we run the Qt application, Py_Initialize() function is getting crashed.

Below is sample code.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("My Python Application");
    Py_SetProgramName("Test Program");

    qDebug() << "Before Initialize";

    Py_Initialize();

    qDebug() << "After Initialize";

    // Shutdown Python
    Py_Finalize();

    return app.exec();  
}
```

I just put the debug statement and came to know that Py_Initialize() is getting failed even though we set the PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH environment variable. We are getting only "Before Initialize" debug print.

NOTE: I observed this issue only in Windows OS. This issue is not observed in Python 2.7. In Linux OS Everything is working fine with Python 2.7 & Python 3.3.4. Issue is only with Windows & Python 3.

Why Py_Initialize() function is getting crashed ? How to solve this issue ?
I have tried with Python 3.3.4 & 3.3.5. In both the version application is getting crashed.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use a debug build of python, run the code under a debugger, and see where it crashes. Only you can answer your question, and that's what you should attempt first.

Comment: Thanks. I found that issue was PYTHONHOME path is not set properly. i used to call Py_SetPythonHome before Py_Initialize and everything is working.

Comment: That doesn't belong in a comment. Answer your own question :)

Answer (score 3):

*Neel answered for himself in a comment, which solved the issue for me too so I thought an answer was in order.*

---

> I found that issue was PYTHONHOME path is not set properly. i used to call Py_SetPythonHome before Py_Initialize and everything is working. – Neel Jul 15 '16 at 11:53

For reference [Py_SetPythonHome (2.7)](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/init.html#c.Py_SetPythonHome) or [Py_SetPythonHome (3.6)](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/init.html#c.Py_SetPythonHome)